# Running multiple JMeter performance tests on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a question regarding JMeter integration with Jenkins and I hope you can help me out.

I have n different jmx(JMeter) files. Currently I'm running a single Jenkins job for each of them with a Windows bash that looks roughly like:

`cd C:\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\ && jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t C:\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\load_tests\testrun.jmx -l C:\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\load_tests\logs\testrun.jtl`

Is it best practice to keep adding new Jenkins jobs for each single test case or is it better to run all tests in one job. Will it give problems later in analyzing the files when I do it in 1 job?

Comment: It seems opinion based question, unless you add more details

Comment: I have no experience with JMeter and this is just my opinion but if you use the xunit plugin to collect the results it's no problem to analyse  multiple result files. Plus it's simpler and you can use parallel steps.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is sticking to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle, to wit instead of having multiple Jenkins jobs you can come up with a single [Parameterized Job](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) and pass new .jmx script and .jtl file names as the job parameters. Check out [Jenkins parameterized build example with String and Boolean parameters](https://www.theserverside.com/video/Modify-CI-jobs-with-this-Jenkins-parameterized-build-example) article for detailed information.

Also depending on what you're trying to achieve you can consider switching from batch files to [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin#reference-jmx-files-and-csv-data) or [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests/) which can execute multiple JMeter .jmx scripts in sequential and parallel manners.